# Having Consistent Client's Session ID in the Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

When a new client connects to the server, the server inserts a record containing the client's `Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId` as the `uuid` field into the Collection named `Active`.

However whenever the server resets, the client is assigned a new `Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId` while the record containing the previous `_lastSessionId` still remain in the Collection.

**Question:** How can we detect the reconnection event, and update the record containing the old `_lastSessionId` with the new one?

Or can we somehow prevent the `_lastSessionId` from changing?

**client/main.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.call('active', Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId)
})
```

**server/main.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'active': function(uuid) {
        Active.insert({'uuid': uuid})
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you mean when the server is reset (you do a hot code push) or when there is a connection issue between the client and server?

Comment: @Akshat During a hot code push and during a forced reset (stop meteor server, and start again). In some cases, Meteor inserted the `_lastSessionId` as `null`, but I cant seem to reproduce it on demand

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent the lastSessionId from changing because the server needs to have a record of the existing session in order to reconnect to it. In the case of a hot code reload the session would be cleared so it would assign a new session Id to the client.

What you could do is either store the new one as an entirely new session or just keep with the first session id as soon as you connect:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
   Meteor.onConnection(function() {
      if(Session.equals("session_id", null)) Session.set("session_id", Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId);
   });
   Meteor.call('active', Session.get("session_id"));
});
```

So this should survive a hot code push on the client, (since `Session` variables are preserved). For the case where the server has a hot code restart, the previous session_id would be used to insert stuff into your logs.

Comment: I don't undersand this code... Meteor.onConnection is a server side function, how can this work?